# Realloc: resetting flexable array of struct within a struct

Tags: c, struct, realloc

I been banging my head on the wall with this one. I was able to narrow it down to the realloc portion of my code.

```
CalStatus readCalComp( FILE *const ics, CalComp **const pcomp )
    {
    CalStatus test;
    CalProp * foldLine;
    CalProp * temp;
    CalComp ** subComp;
    char * buffer;
    static int depth = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    buffer = NULL;
    foldLine = NULL;
    subComp = NULL;

    if (depth == 0)
    {
        test = readCalLine (ics, &buffer);

        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            return test;
        }
        foldLine = malloc (sizeof (CalProp));
        assert (foldLine != NULL);
        test.code = parseCalProp (buffer, foldLine);
        free (buffer);

        if ((strcmp ("BEGIN", foldLine->name) == 0) && ((strcmp ("VCALENDAR", foldLine->value) == 0)))
        {
            (*pcomp)->name = malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(foldLine->value)+1);
            assert ((*pcomp)->name != NULL);
            strcpy((*pcomp)->name, foldLine->value);
            depth = depth + 1;

            free(foldLine->name);
            free(foldLine->value);
            free(foldLine);

            while ((buffer != NULL) && (test.code == OK) && (depth > 0))
            {
                test = readCalLine (ics, &buffer);

                if (buffer != NULL)
                {
                    foldLine = malloc (sizeof(CalProp));
                    assert (foldLine != NULL);
                    test.code = parseCalProp (buffer, foldLine);
                    free (buffer);

                    if ((strcmp ("END", foldLine->name) == 0) && ((strcmp ("VCALENDAR", foldLine->value) == 0) || (strcmp ("VCALENDAR\r\n", foldLine->value) == 0) ))
                    {
                        depth = depth - 1;

                        free(foldLine->name);
                        free(foldLine->value);
                        free(foldLine);

                        return test;
                    }
                    else if (strcmp ("BEGIN", foldLine->name) == 0)
                    {
                        subComp = malloc(sizeof (CalComp *));
                        *subComp = malloc(sizeof(CalComp) + (1*sizeof(CalComp*)));

                        (*subComp)-> name = NULL;
                        (*subComp)-> nprops = 0;
                        (*subComp)-> prop = NULL;
                        (*subComp)-> ncomps = 0;
                        (*subComp)-> comp[0] = NULL;

                        (*subComp)-> name = malloc(sizeof(char) *strlen(foldLine->value)+1);
                        strcpy((*subComp)->name, foldLine->value);

                        if ((*pcomp)-> ncomps == 0)
                        {
                            (*pcomp)->comp[(*pcomp)->ncomps] = *subComp;
                            (*pcomp)->ncomps += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            (*pcomp)->ncomps += 1;
                            *pcomp = realloc(*pcomp, sizeof(CalComp) + (2*sizeof(CalComp*)));
                            (*pcomp)->comp[(*pcomp)->ncomps-1] = *subComp;
                        }

                        depth = depth + 1;

                        test = readCalComp (ics, subComp);
                    }
                } // end of if buffer NULL
            }// end of While
        } // end of if VCALENDAR
    } // End of if Depth
    else
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            test = readCalLine (ics, &buffer);
            count += 1;
        }

        while ((test.code == OK) && (buffer != NULL))
        {
            if (count != 1)
            {
                test = readCalLine (ics, &buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            if (buffer != NULL)
            {
                foldLine = malloc (sizeof(CalProp));
                test.code = parseCalProp (buffer, foldLine);
                free (buffer);

                if ((strcmp ("END", foldLine->name) == 0) && ((strcmp ((*pcomp)->name, foldLine->value) == 0)))
                {
                    depth = depth - 1;

                    free (foldLine->name);
                    free (foldLine->value);
                    free (foldLine);

                    return test;
                }
                else if (strcmp ("BEGIN", foldLine->name) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Success in malloc 2!\n");
                    subComp = malloc(sizeof (CalComp *));
                    *subComp = malloc(sizeof(CalComp) + (1*sizeof(CalComp*)));

                    (*subComp)-> name = NULL;
                    (*subComp)-> nprops = 0;
                    (*subComp)-> prop = NULL;
                    (*subComp)-> ncomps = 0;
                    (*subComp)-> comp[0] = NULL;

                    (*subComp)-> name = malloc(sizeof(char) *strlen(foldLine->value)+1);
                    strcpy ((*subComp)->name, foldLine->value);

                    if ((*pcomp)-> ncomps == 0)
                    {
                        (*pcomp)->comp[(*pcomp)->ncomps] = *subComp;
                        (*pcomp)->ncomps += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        (*pcomp)->ncomps += 1;
                        (*pcomp) = realloc(*pcomp, sizeof(CalComp) + (2*sizeof(CalComp*)));
                        (*pcomp)->comp[(*pcomp)->ncomps-1] = *subComp;
                        printf ("First subcomponent is %s\n", (*pcomp)->comp[0]->name);
                        printf ("Second subcomponent is %s\n", (*pcomp)->comp[1]->name);
                    }

                    depth = depth + 1;

                    test = readCalComp (ics, subComp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

        return test;
  }
```

CalComp is a struct that consists of:

```
char * name;

int numProps;

CalProp *prop (linked list);

int numComp;

CalComp *comp[] (flexible array);
```

Checking inside the function, the name of the structs within the flexible array is correct, but when I try to access the names outside of the function, it either NULL value or been set to the name of the first linked list node of the structure.

Due to the nature of the assignment, I can not modify Calcomp struct nor the function parameters. The function must be recursive, and the flexible array must adjust based on need.

As I said before, I narrowed it down to the realloc, by printing out the values within the flexible array. The bug occurs when the program reallocs.

FYI, I have tried reallocing to a temp variable, checked to see if NULL and then assigned that one to pcomp but didn't help.

Comment: You have a lot of repeated code to initialize `CalComp` and `CalProp`. When dealing with structs I always write a `structname_new` and a `structname_destroy` to encapsulate that sometimes tricky part of the code. Try doing that and see if that makes it easier to debug. If not, repost your problem with the better encapsulated code.

Comment: I just want to mention, that commeting out all free functions results in the flexible array name containing END.

Comment: I figured out what was causing the problem. When I use realloc on a recursive call, it may change the memory address location. Due to the recursive call, there was nothing to catch the change in address in the parent node. Therefore it got filled with garbage. Man was that annoying. Fixed by using a static helper function to hold the address and placing it back in after the recursive call comes back.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `realloc`, you're not including `ncomp` in the additional size for the flexible structure, you're just hard-coding it to `2`.

```
(*pcomp) = realloc(*pcomp, sizeof(CalComp) + (*pcomp->ncomps * sizeof(CalComp*)));
```

Comment: I removed (*pcomp)->ncomps to see if it has bad data in it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

`(*pcomp) = realloc(*pcomp, sizeof(CalComp) + (2*sizeof(CalComp*)));`

change above line to

```
pcomp = realloc(*pcomp, sizeof(CalComp) + (2*sizeof(CalComp*)));
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  assignment of read-only parameter ‘pcomp’. Thanks though.